# Adding background to ImageButton Android

Tags: android-studio, imagebutton, android-drawable, android-resources

I have an issue which displays:

```
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name 
(at 'background' with value '@drawable/unpressed').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
'Drive:\Users\...\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Basically I want to add background to an ImageButton which will change after `OnTouch()` Event. For that first of all, I have to add an Image (a simple scenario without an Event)

---

I am facing the above mentioned problem in a simple case. I don't know what mistake am I making. My code for ImageButton is:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
    android:background="@drawable/unpressed"
/>
```

I have tried all of the solutions searched including:

- Clean Solution
- Rebuild Solution
- Update SDK (mentioned in STACK Solution) Libraries
- File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
- After pasting image in `drawable`, synchronized it.

As iGoda informed in the Comments. How can I find where the R settings exactly are changed?

Comment: Do you have the drawable on the drawable folder or some specific version as drawable-v21

Comment: Image is specifically/directly pasted in a **drawable** folder. i basically don't know how technically is it right. @iGoDa

Comment: Technically you should make a bunch of drawable with specific dimensions for each size (hdpi, xhdpi, etc). Or using vectorial imagens. But that's not the error here.

Comment: Then what should i do Man. I am stuck and not able to resolve it, causing stress.

Comment: This can be because your R is not being generated properly because of some error on a xml file ou class. Try to start from there, sry I could not help you more :-(

Comment: Any help about R, as i am a starter in Android Platform. It would be great! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, the problem solved by:

- deleting the files in the path:
  `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp`
- If any of the folder in above path is not visible to you, kindly show the hidden files by going into the following Options in the menu bar of Windows Explorer: `Organize -> Folder and Search Options`(For Windows-7)

  - Restart system and then check. It will all be fine.